# Registry not working in magento 2

Tags: blocks, magento2.2.6, admin-controller, registry

I need to call the controller function from block . in magento 2 i use the registry. 
In my block i wrote

```
public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,            
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_cardsManageFactory = $cardsManageFactory;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }
public function getMydata()
{
 return  $this->registry->registry('controller_data');}
```

in my admin controller i wrote

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }
public function execute()
{
     .....
     ......
     .....  some calculation did here
     $response = $calculation;
     $this->registry->register('controller_data', $response);
}
```

while i call block from phtml

```
$data = $block->getMydata();
```

i got error `Notice: Undefined property:`

Comment: can you please share controller's execute function

Answer (score 1):

you have define registry variable this

> **$this->_registry**

but you are using below:

> **$this->registry**

that's why you getting error:

try

> **$this->_registry->registry('controller_data');**

Comment: i changed now i am not facing error . i got empty resonse . while i print response in block i got nothing it is blank

Comment: i call registry in block and assign register in admin controller is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to set frontend registry to backend controller?

Comment: I did same calculation in both controller and block , i call controller function via ajax. block code via phtml load. i need to simplify the code. so i need to call admin controller via block. while i search i found registry. so i try to found whether it is working or not

Comment: So you can abstct controller for it and you can use at admin as well as at front side

Answer (score 0):

Please don't  `redefine` the  function name `getData()`.

Changes the function name `getData()` to other like `public function getMyData()`

and  call this **phtml**  using  `$block->getMyData();`

Comment: Now i got the empty resonse

Comment: In your construct I can see you defined as `$this->_registry` and in method you are using `$this->registry` @SammuSundar

Comment: aah my mistake..

Comment: This solves error but it returns empty response

Comment: @AmitBera How to resolve empty response. I am using <argument name="slider_id" xsi:type="helper" helper="<Vendor>\<Module>\Helper\Data::getSliderId"></argument>